# how to tune and demo

Tags: digital-communications, theory

How does one go about tunning your fm demod algorithm to a given carrier frequency.

Consider the following  algorithms that are present in this website:

[DSP Tricks: Frequency demodulation algorithms](https://www.embedded.com/dsp-tricks-frequency-demodulation-algorithms/)

Question:

How does someone go about tuning the algorithms to a specified freq for fm demod.

Let X be your carrier frequency in kHz.

Using X this will be a factor in how the algorithm will demodulate.

Is it possible to do this or is a bandpass filter required to filter the required signal that has the stuff before applying a transform to get your I&Q signals.

Comment: What is  meant by "turning" an fm demod algorithm?

Comment: You put "tuning your FM demod algorithm" in quotes -- so you're quoting someone.  But the article you cite does not talk about tuning the algorithm.  Please _edit your question_ to expand on what you mean by that phrase, or if you're lifting it from some source, _edit your question_ to cite that source.  I _assume_ that you mean how do you _modify_ your algorithm to your specific situation -- you may want to _tell us_ what your situation is -- frequencies, sampling rates, signal bandwidth, deviation, and any concerns about processing power would probably complete the question.

Comment: @TimWescott is that better?

Comment: When I said "frequencies, sampling rates, signal bandwidth, deviation, and any concerns about processing power would probably complete the question," that's exactly what I meant.  **Your question is unclear**.  Tell us the carrier frequency going into the demodulator, the sample rate, the signal bandwidth the deviation, and whether you have infinite processing power or not.  Then maybe we can _start_ to answer.  Or, better yet, _try it out_, and come back if you have any specific questions.

Comment: @TimWescott ping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ben Madison. The “Embedded” people who posted that material on the Internet changed my first sentence. And that change omitted important information. That FM demod discussion is an application of the Hilbert transform. That is, the $i(n)$ signal is a real-valued FM signal that has been bandpass filtered to maximize its signal-to-noise ratio. So the only “tuning” taking place was whatever processing was needed to produce the $i(n)$ samples.

We apply the $i(n)$ signal to a Hilbert transformer to generate the $q(n)$ samples. (The $i(n)$ signal must be delayed in time to synchronize the $i(n)$ and $q(n)$ samples.) So the $i(n) + jq(n)$ samples comprise a complex-valued signal sequence that only has positive-frequency spectral components.

So, once you have the $i(n)$ and $q(n)$ samples available you can perform FM demodulation using the networks in Figure 13-60 or Figure 13-61.